# how to understand code like this pKataLengkap.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")

Tags: java, string

can anyone describe what's mean of code below this

```
pKataLengkap.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")
```

i dont understand, im get some reference from [link from code fight](https://codefights.com/challenge/gW4krDGQ8cPHGaJyh) 
thanks!

Comment: Learn Regular Expressions in general and Capturing Groups in particular.

Comment: okey i will learn about that

Answer (score 4):

`replaceAll` replaces regular expressions (regexes).  If you don't understand anything about regexes, you should read [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  However, this particular regex is a bit on the tricky side, so I'll explain it.  The regex is `(.)\1+` (the backslash has to be doubled in a string literal, but the regex only has one backslash).

The first `.` matches any single character.  Since it's in parentheses, the matcher treats this as a "capturing group"; since it's the first group in the regex, it's "capturing group 1".  When a match is found (i.e. when the matcher finds any single character), the text of that match will be the capturing group.  Thus, "capturing group 1" is that one character.

The next part is `\1+`.  `+` is a quantifier meaning "one or more of whatever the + follows".  `\1` is a special pattern that means "whatever is in capturing group 1".  So what this all means is that the pattern will match any single character followed by one or more occurrences of that same character.  That is, it matches patterns with two or more occurrences of the same character.

Now each such pattern is replaced by `"$1"`.  The `$1` is special in `replaceAll`, and it means "the contents of the capturing group 1", which is the single character that got matched.

So basically, any time the matcher sees two or more consecutive occurrences of the same character, it will replace them with *one* occurrence of that character.  That is, it will transform `"xxxyyyyyyzzz"` to `"xyz"`.

Comment: your explanation realy-really-really helpful. thank you so much! God Bless you.